# Como fazer um Trigger animationend sem JQuery?

Tags: javascript

Como é possível fazer um `.trigger` sem utilizar jQuery?

Por exemplo, vi que é possível com o `event` `click` utilizar o `element.click();`, mas e quando o `event` é `animationend`?

Em jQuery, seria equivalente a:  `$( "#element" ).trigger( "animationend" );`

Comment: sua pergunta falta detalhes para responder, tem algum exemplo?

Comment: dê uma olhada no codigo fonte do jquery para entender e fazer o que deseja, está tudo no github: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/40c3abd0ab049449acab5f2e12c34b9cc3199482/src/event/trigger.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O básico seria usar `var event = new Event('animationend')` com `<Element>.dispatchEvent(event);`, exemplo aplicado com `addEventListener` e `onanimationend`

```js
var elementoAnimado = document.querySelector('#exemplo');

elementoAnimado.addEventListener('animationend', (event) => {
    console.log('Element.addEventListener(animationend) #1', event.target);
});

elementoAnimado.onanimationend = (event) => {
    console.log('Element.onanimationend = () => {}', event.target);
};

elementoAnimado.addEventListener('animationend', (event) => {
    console.log('Element.addEventListener(animationend) #2', event.target);
});

function disparar()
{
     elementoAnimado.dispatchEvent(new Event('animationend'));
}
```

```html
<div id="exemplo">Exemplo</div>

<button onclick="disparar()">Disparar</button>
```

Vale lembrar que navegadores antigos usavam `document.createEvent('Event')`, como o Internet Explorer, se precisar executar isso terá que aplica-lo.

Atualmente a documentação mais razoável para se aprender o básico de JavaScript esta no MDN, recomendo que estudo o básico:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault